# Cannot render list created in one component in another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok. I have the app.js (which will render all components on my screen) and inside this file i embeded two other js files (components). The first one is basically a button that adds one more word to an array. It goes something like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function DescriptionSector() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState([]);
  return (
    <button onClick={() => setTitle([...title, "New title defined"])}>add word</button>

)
```

This first component is working just fine as I used console.log to test it.

THe problem is with the second part.
The second part consists basically of a list that renders the array create on the first part and here's where i having trouble.

```
function FinancialResume({ title }) {
  return (

    <ul>

      {title.map(e => {
      return (
        <li>{e}</li>
        
      )
    })}

    </ul>


  )

}
```

I tried using the props object to send the updated array like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function DescriptionSector() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState([]);
  return (
     <button
        onClick={() => {
          setTitle([...title, "New title defined"]);
          FinancialResume(title);
        }}
      >
        add word
      </button>

)
```

**BUT IT DIDNT WORKED**

EDIT: here's my app.js

```
import DescriptionSector from "./Components/descriptionSector/description";
import FinancialResume from "./Components/financialresume/financialresume";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <div className="user-body__leftSector">
        <DescriptionSector />        
      </div>

      <div className="user-body__rightSector">
        <FinancialResume />
      </div>
    </div>

)}
            
export default App;
```

Comment: Please show your App.js

Comment: just updateded it

Comment: Are you wanting to share the state set by `DescriptionSector` with the `FinancialResume` component? Ie, `DescriptionSector` sets the `title` and then `FinancialResume` renders the changes

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the changes made in `DescriptionSector` to be rendered by `FinancialResume`, one way you can do that with React is by passing props from a shared parent.

Let `App` control the `title` state. It can pass the setter down to `DescriptionSector` and the value down to `FinancialResume`.

React states are reactive to changes. `App` and `FinancialResume` will re-render when `title` changes without you having to call any functions.

```jsx
function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="user-body__leftSector">
        <DescriptionSector setTitle={setTitle} />
      </div>

      <div className="user-body__rightSector">
        <FinancialResume title={title} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```jsx
function DescriptionSector({ setTitle }) {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setTitle((title) => [...title, "New title defined"]);
      }}
    >
      add word
    </button>
  );
}
```

```jsx
function FinancialResume({ title }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {title.map((e, i) => {
        return <li key={i}>{e}</li>;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit young-tdd-k6ttf5]

There are of course other ways to manage shared state such as [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and state stores like [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) but those are more advanced topics.